# Pass method from sub-object to method of 1st(head) object declared as NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

As topic as topic. That problem exists from class `ObjectSubA`, i can't call method of object `ObjectX`. At one condition methods must have same name of method.

*file.h*

```
@interface ObjectX : NSObject 
- (void) insert; 
@end 

@interface ObjectSubA : ObjectX 
- (void) insert; 
@end 

@interface ObjectSubB : ObjectX 
@end
```

*file.m*

```
@implementation ObjectX 
- (void) insert{ 
NSLog(@"answer"); 
} 
@end 
@implementation ObjectSubA 
-(void)insert{ 
NSLog(@"nothing") 
[self insert]; // <- need answer, should call insert from ObjectX
} 
@end 
@implementation ObjectSubB 
@end 

@implementation app 
-(void)launch{ 
ObjectSubA * a = [[ObjectSubA alloc]init]; 
[a insert]; // ObjectSubA -> method insert -> ObjectX -> insert -> end. #ERROR 
ObjectSubB * b = [[ObjectSubB alloc] init]; 
[b insert]; //ObjectX -> insert -> end. OK 
} 
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just call `super`

```
- (void)insert{ 
  NSLog(@"nothing");
  [super insert]; 
}
```

From the Objective-C documentation

> **Objects Can Call Methods Implemented by Their Superclasses**
>
> There’s another important keyword available to you in Objective-C, called `super`. Sending a message to `super` is a way to call through to a method implementation defined by a superclass further up the inheritance chain. The most common use of `super` is when overriding a method.

Comment: Additionally, you don’t need to define `insert` in the ObjectSubA interface if it was already defined in the parent interface. Just have the implementation in ObjectSubA.

Comment: Of course, but I suspect there is more code involved than the log line

Comment: Thank u! that worked ;) already i have forgotten about `super`.